# Android: startActivity() in a class that extends View

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 3 classes: MainActivity,DrawView and SecondActivity.
MainActivity just use DrawView to draw something on the screen. How can I start SecondActivity when i touch the screen on an Bitmap, I know where is the bitmap(in the code).
The onTouchEvent function from DrawView class.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
     switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            float posX = ev.getX();
            float posY = ev.getY();
            if(play.touched(posX, posY)==true){

            } else {
            }
            return true;
        }

}
     return false;
}
```

The function `play.touched(posX,posY)` return a boolean value(I made a class that handel the position of the Bitmap). How can I start Second Activity from here?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203019/how-to-start-one-activity-from-customized-view

Answer (score 10):

```
        if(play.touched(posX, posY)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            ((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(intent);
        } else {
        }
```

Comment: I can`t call startActivity(Intent) in a class what extends View.

Comment: Try that way... it will work if you created the DrawView from your activity. Otherwise... you will have to implement something like the Observer Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if(play.touched(posX, posY)){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    super.getContext().startActivity(intent);
} else {
}
```