# How to start one activity from Customized View

Tags: android, view, android-activity, android-intent

How to start one activity  from another View (another activity View)

For example,

```
public class CorrectSmoothGloflo extends Activity {
  .......................
  setContentView(new Panel(this));
}


public class Panel extends View {

   //This view class contains some drawable operation
   // Here i want to start another Activity like this

   Intent i=new Intent(CorrectSmoothGloflo.this,Screen.class);
    startActivity(i);   
}
```

I cant do this operation. Because this is the View, that will not work, because View does not have `startActivity()`. How to implement this? please give some guidelines.

Answer (score 27):

Obtain a `Context` object and use its `startActivity()` method:

```
Context context = getContext();
Intent i = new Intent(context, Screen.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup an event handler to your "another activity View", and put the activity calling statements in it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent i=new Intent(CorrectSmoothGloflo.this,Screen.class); 
startActivity(i);
```

as you want to start another activity so u need to pass current context and not the previous like i your example your are mentioned correctsmoothgloflo but it is panel.class

check this is help for u or not...

Comment: my PAnel class is non activity class. thats y problem to call another activity.  In this situvation what can i do?